# How to temporarily remove limit on ufw logging rule

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, bash, ufw

I'm trying to debug some ufw firewall rules, but I've found that the logs don't consistently log the connections. It appears this might be because ufw adds limits to the underlying iptables rules:

```
web01:~$ sudo iptables -L | grep -i "log"
[sudo] password for webuser:
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT INVALID] "
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
```

How do I temporarily remove the limit from the ALLOW log rules so that the logs show all connections that are allowed through the ufw firewall?